# SceneKit camera not moving to proper location

Tags: swift, xcode, scenekit, swift-playground

I am working on a solar system swift playground. I want the camera to zoom into a planet if that planet is clicked. The current issue I am having is that the camera won't zoom into the right location. Here is the code I am using.

```
public let camera = SCNNode()
camera.camera = SCNCamera()
camera.position = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: -70, z: 50)
camera.eulerAngles = SCNVector3(x: 0.74533, y: 0, z: 0)

let location = planetNodes[i].convertPosition(planetNodes[i].position, to: camera)
let radius = planetNodes[i].position.y
let moveCameraAc = SCNAction.move(to: location, duration: 2)
moveCameraAc.timingMode = .easeInEaseOut
camera.runAction(moveCameraAc)
```

It will always move to a different location in the scene. I am unable to figure out how is it finding out where to move to.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think you should be converting the position of the planet to the parent node of the camera instead of the camera itself.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. The parent node is scene.rootNode. I tried that, and that also didn't work. Any idea what else could be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I have figured it out! The code needs to look like

```
let location = holderNodes[i].convertPosition(planetNodes[i].position, to: scene.rootNode)
```

holderNodes[i] is the parent of planetNodes[i] and scene.rootNode is the parent node of camera.